# HTML table not align in phpmail function

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer

I am taking data from database and put it in html table that html table looks fine but when i press the send button for email send some times the html table is not aligned in email,it looks like below the date is not align in the specific coloumn

[image]

also like this

[image]

i don't why it showing "!". can any one guide why this happens,thanks

my code:

```
$text_mail.= "<table style='border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;'>
<tr >
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>Country</th>
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>Network Name </th>
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>MCC</th>
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>MNC</th> 
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>Old Price (Euro)</th>        
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>New Price (Euro)</th>        
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>Change</th>      
<th style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px'>Valid From (DD.MM.YYYY) </th>        
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes))
{

    if($row['pricefrom']==0){

        $pricefrom="NA";
        $change="New Network";

    }else{

        $pricefrom= $row['pricefrom'];
        $change= $row['statusto'];

    }

    if($row['priceto']==0){

        $priceto="NA";
        $change="Not Covered";

    }else{

        $priceto= $row['priceto'];
        $change= $row['statusto'];


    }   


$text_mail.= "<tr>";
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['networkname'] . "</td>";
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['mcc'] . "</td>";
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['mnc'] . "</td>"; 
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $pricefrom . "</td>"; 
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $priceto . "</td>"; 
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $change . "</td>"; 
$text_mail.= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" .date('d.m.Y', $row['datetime']) . "</td>"; 
$text_mail.= "</tr>";
}
$text_mail.= "</table> <br><br>";
```

Comment: You really should not send html emails. html based emails are one of the biggest security problems in todays information technology. Consider using a short plain text email and a link to a page showing that html instead. Much more secure, less annoying, less load on all systems, more people who can read your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this:

```
$text_mail.= "<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['country'] . "</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['networkname'] . "</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['mcc'] . "</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $row['mnc'] . "</td> 
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $pricefrom . "</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $priceto . "</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" . $change . "</td> 
<td style='border:1px solid black; width:130px; padding:0 0 0 5px;'><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>" .date('d.m.Y', $row['datetime']) . "</td>
</tr>";
```